# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch in ruby

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-ruby

I am trying to accessing the list_cloud_services from azure in ruby but its giving the error as

(byebug) client.list_cloud_services
*** Faraday::SSLError Exception: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch

nil

Comment: Are you able to provide the code/command portion which relevant to the error above?

Comment: @juvchan: i have configure the Azure server with the help of this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) and i have uploaded certificate to the server and i have kept the .pem file in my system wiht the help of this (**vm_management = Azure.vm_management**) i am creating the client and when i use **vm_management.list_cloud_services** i am getting the above error